# What should be the table schema for hierarchical data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, hierarchical-data

I have just attended an interview, where I was given a question including this scenario and some sample data:

`A` is a boss of `B`, `C` and `D`. 
`D` is the boss of `E` and `F`. 
Then `F` is the boss of `G` and `H`, ie we have hierarchical data.

In another way we can say that there is project manager, team leader then developer. Now we want to create table to store the data.

Further, a developer can later become a project manager.

So how should we create the table? What columns should the table contain?

My answer was:

We should have one table for project manager which contains columns `PM_ID` and `PM_Name` where `PM_ID` is the primary key. Then we should create another table for team leaders. In that table we should have `TL_ID` as primary key, `TL_Name` and `PM_ID` as foreign key.

Then we should create developer table in that we should have `D_ID` as primary key, `D_Name` and then `TL_ID` as foreign key.

Can you please tell me whether I have provided the correct schema for the table?

If anything is wrong then can you please provide me with what should be the correct schema for the above case?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx http://vyaskn.tripod.com/hierarchies_in_sql_server_databases.htm

Comment: The problem with having separate tables for different roles is you need to add tables as roles change.  It's also harder to do queries like CTEs and "under" queries.  there's many approaches but a single table is common between all of them.

Comment: The problem was poorly specified.  Is the hierarchy one relating employees to other employees (Joe reports to Fred) on one relating job slots to other job slots  (Team leader  for team X1 reports to project manager for project x)?  If it's the former, then some of the answers point you to a single table solution that goes by the name of "Adjacency List".

Answer (score 2):

You more than likely need a hierarchy table http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677174%28v=sql.100%29.aspx and then use a cte query to display the results.

Answer (score 1):

- When a developer becomes a project manager, does that person cease to be a developer?
- All these relationships can change over time. Do you need to know which relationships have changed, and when they changed?
- Does every person have to have a boss?
- Does every boss have to have subordinates?
- When a boss dies or leaves, what happens to that boss's subordinates?
- Can a developer work for more than one team leader at a time?

Sometimes, interview questions are less about the structure, and more about your ability to recognize and resolve ambiguity in the requirements.  (Also, not that it's necessarily relevant here, but when most people point at something and say "hierarchy", if you look closer you'll find "network".)

Answer (score 0):

In this case your table needs to have a Foreign key to itself.

Comment: AD.Net, Rechard aka cyberkiwi. I have referred the link http://vyaskn.tripod.com/hierarchies_in_sql_server_databases.htm. I think you are talking about such type of hierarchical table. In that if the software engineer becomes project manager then the above hirarchy is proper?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest table is going to contain this information (in just one table):

```
EmployeeID | LineManager | Role
-----------+-------------+-----
A          | A           | boss
B          | A           | pm
C          | A           | pm
D          | A           | pm
E          | D           | tl
F          | D           | tl
G          | F           | dev
H          | F           | dev
```